# obout gridview row command

Tags: asp.net, gridview, edit, obout

Hey i am trying to use a specific gridview from obout toolkit and i am wondering if any chance someone using it as well and  knows how to get to the "Edit" command?  for example in the regular asp.net gridview all i had to do is use funciton :

```
Protected Sub approvalGrid_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles approvalGrid.RowCommand
```

and then something like

```
If (e.CommandName = "Edit") Then
    .
    .
    .
```

but there is no such thing with obout gridview and i been spending half a day trying to find out how can
i access this event  when a user clicks the `Edit`-button on the `gridview`.

Answer (score 0):

By attaching an event handler to the `OnClientSelect` event you can use the record selection feature of the Grid to put the selected record in edit mode. This approach makes it easier for end users to edit records, without being needed to locate and click the "Edit" links.

http://www.obout.com/grid/aspnet_commands_onclick.aspx

Comment: Hey the problem is that i need to make a template for editing with a form and different controls etc  i cant keep it like the regular one.

Comment: http://www.obout.com/grid/grid_tutorials_templates.aspx and http://www.obout.com/grid/grid_templates.aspx